# How can I get the theme spacing unit in MUI 5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In past versions of MUI, one could get the theme spacing unit via `theme.spacing.unit`, which at default values would output `8`, but that property has been removed in MUI 5. I can't find documentation to get access to the theme spacing unit. How do I get that value (without the `px`)?

Comment: please check https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `theme.spacing.unit` its related to `v3` and it was already deprecated in version 4 as you can see [here](https://v4.mui.com/guides/migration-v3/#theme).

For v5 (and v4), MUI uses a recommended 8px scaling factor by default and you can get the unit with `theme.spacing(1)`.

Spacing samples:

```js
const theme = createTheme();

theme.spacing(2); // `${8 * 2}px` = '16px'

// OR

const theme = createTheme({
  spacing: 4,
});

theme.spacing(2); // `${4 * 2}px` = '8px'
```

You can check more about it in v5 [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/spacing/#main-content).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't quite solve what I need. I need the pixel value without the `px`, so I could do `parseInt(theme.spacing(1))`, but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The theme spacing units get inherently converted when using the `sx` prop.
https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#spacing

```
<Grid sx={{ paddingLeft: 1 }>
```

is Equivalent to

```
const StyledGrid = styled(Grid)(({ theme }) => ({
  paddingLeft: theme.spacing(1)
}))
```

Comment: this should be clearer in the doco!